# Apollo cache local filters and pagination

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a graphql api with bunch of filters and pagination available.

Is it possible to make Apollo filter already fetched results locally and only query the server if there are pages remaining?

For example, let us have Users with Name and Role filters, and 20 results per page.

We start with filtered query (name: Alice) and get 15 results. If we add a second filter (role: Admin) the app should do the filtering locally.

Or we start with (role: Admin) and get 50 results. Now we add a second filter (name: Alice) and the app should instantly filter whatever Alices were present at the first page, yet do the second query, and update the list once it's complete. Then if we remove the first filter, the app should do another query without local filtering at all, cause there may be non-Admin Alices ordered first.

Comment: sure, in ideal world ... different filters, different entries in cache ... you can fight at app level ... but is it worth to save one request? premature optimization? wishlist send to maintainers

Comment: @xadm Well my actual app is all about multi-filtering, so the optimization is supposed to save much more than one request. And I'm just not sure of Apollo capabilities — it can handle pagination or local reducers alone, but no way to do both?